# Why is the British tv show "the Undatables" not called "the Undatable" without 's'?

Tags: grammar, british-english, articles

There is a tv series on Channel 4 called "The Undatables" which I have just started watching.

The title keeps me wondering why it's not just called "the undatable" like the poor or the rich?

Last time I checked my grammar book, you only need an adjective after "the" to refer to a certain type of people.

Can you at least tell me why do you think the producer decided to make it plural by putting the "s" at the end?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for steering clear of why there isn't an apostrophe :)

Comment: @AffableGeek Sorry? I don't get what you're trying to say. You thought I would ask why there's no apostrophe in the title?

Answer (score 2):

The "invincible" would be a general reference to anyone deemed invincible.

The "invincible seven" would mean seven particular persons or entities who are described as invincible.

The "invincibles" would be the appropriate proper name of a group, presumably of people, who wish to project themselves as being invincible.

The "undateable" is a general reference to anyone who is undateable.

The "undateables" would be an appropriate proper name/noun of a particular group, but not all, who are undateable.

BTW, the TV show is "undateables" not "undatables".

"Undatable" would mean being incapable of dealing with "data".

Comment: I assume your comment about "undatatable" is meant to be humorous...

Comment: You seem downright *possessed* by this argument. :)

Comment: OK, I edited the answer so that "undatatable" is now "undatable".

Comment: Is either geek datable?

Answer (score 1):

*Undateable* is an adjective used here as a noun.

However, **poor** and **rich**, in addition to being adjectives, are also [mass nouns](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun).

As mass nouns, they are treated as singular parts of speech even when they are inherently plural.

As such, you *normally* say, 'the blues', 'the untouchables', but because 'poor' and 'rich' are also mass nouns, you say 'the poor', 'the rich'.

Comment: Could someone explain to me why this is being voted down?  This is the grammatically correct explanation.

Comment: "Poor" and "rich" are adjectives just like the words "young" and "restless". No need to treat them specially. As far as I know, it's a grammatical rule that when "the" is followed by an adjective, it becomes a noun which refers to a group of people. The young and the restless for instance. It's the same with the rich and the poor.